# Where to put Latex generic commands?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, packages

Using more and more Latex I reach a point where I don't want to copy/paste anymore the new "generic" commands I created.

As an example, I have generic commands to create Tikz pictures. These commands are generic enough (using parameters) in order to be used in different contexts. After searching on google, I din't get a clear view on the different ways to do that.

Where can I put such commands, how include them and what are the benefits/drawbacks for the different solutions ? I guess, I can create packages, include files, other ...

Comment: Thanks for the duplicate's link and sorry for the duplicate, but I didn't find it before asking.